# Azure Event Grid | Topic per event

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I'll get different types of events from the client. There will be 5-6 event types and Azure Functions app will consume these events. Load to Event Grid won't be so high, let's say between 5-10k per event type per day.

I don't want to leave best practices whether the project is small or big. So, according to information I shared, should I create a topic per event type or just create a topic and filter them by subjects?

Comment: This is too little information to enable us to give you funded advise. For instance: how many event types will there be? How many events approximately? How many publishers? What about consumers? Also, this might get some opinion-based answers which is something that is frowned upon over here at SO. Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be creating topic per event type rather than creating one and filtering by subject

> Using the **Events** page of a resource, for example, Storage Account or Event Hubs Namespace. When you use the **Events** page in the Azure portal to create an event subscription for an event raised by an Azure source (for example: Azure Storage account), the portal creates a system topic for the Azure resource and then creates a subscription for the system topic. You specify the name of the system topic if you are creating an event subscription on the Azure resource for the first time. From the second time onwards, the system topic name is displayed for you in the read-only mode. See [Quickstart: Route Blob storage events to web endpoint with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/blob-event-quickstart-portal#subscribe-to-the-blob-storage) for detailed steps.

Here are the few Microsoft links which have information about event grid [system topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/create-view-manage-system-topics) and [custom topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-topics) creation.